Non-hermitian Hamiltonian $H^1(t)=H^1e^{−i\omega t}$ on Wikipedia page for Rabi problem
I read about the Rabi problem at Wikipedia, but there is something I don't understand. They introduce a periodic perturbation $$H^1(t)=H^1e^{−i\omega t}.$$ But isn't this hamiltonian non-hermitian? Specifically, the hermitian adjoint would look like $$H^1(t)^{\dagger}=(H^1)^{\dagger} e^{i\omega t}.$$
This is different from $H^1(t)$ whenever $\omega\neq0$.

It's in the section `Rabi problem in time-dependent perturbation theory'. At least the mathematical expression is exactly as I stated it.

This is only one half of a physical Hamiltonian.  The correct Hamiltonian should be
$$
H_1(e^{-i\omega t}+e^{i\omega t})
$$
but the treatment for periodic perturbation has an integration where the only significant contribution is determined by the energy conservation condition
$E_i-E_f=\pm \hbar \omega$.  In other words, once you do away with the integration over time, only one of $\pm \omega$ leads to a significant contribution, while the other is neglected.
The advantage of using the truncated form with one frequency is to simplify the algebra; the truncated form is very convenient to derive Fermi's Golden rule for instance. The cost (as you realized) is some confusion as to the hermiticity of $H$.

Can wikipedia be clarified using some easy edit?

Maybe but I only do PSE edits....  ;)

I sometimes edit wikipedia, but I don't feel confident enough to edit this page. I might put a message there that someone else has to look at it.
